# How to show property descriptions in Windows Store App User Control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime

I usually use description attribute for custom properties in WPF user control as below.

```
        [Category("Features"), Description("You can setup image width ratio in double type")]
    public double ImageWidthRatio
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageWidthRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageWidthRatioProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageWidthRatioProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthRatioProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidthRatio", typeof(double), typeof(TheControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0));
```

The line `[Category("Features"), Description("You can setup image width ratio")]` gives descriptions with groups in Properties window.

But, is Windows Store App User Control. It says no `System.ComponentModel.DesriptionAttribute`.

How to show my property descriptions in Properties window in WinRT?

Answer (score 0):

Add this helper class

```
using System;

namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public DescriptionAttribute(string description)
        {
            Description = description;
        }

        public string Description { get; private set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == this)
                return true;

            var other = obj as DescriptionAttribute;
            return other != null && other.Description == Description;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Description.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: // thanks for the quick reply. your codes actually make `Description` attribute, but it does not give information in Properties panel as WPF. so we can judge that there's no way to "show description in properties window", right?